# fail to authenticate with managed identity for Azure SQL DB using Azure data factory

Tags: database, azure-data-factory

I have created an azure SQL Database ,and trying to create a linked service with this database, but failed with managed identity authentication type.

error messages:

Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'alexwang.database.windows.net', Database: 'alexSQLDatabase', User: ''. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access. Login failed for user ''., SqlErrorNumber=18456,Class=14,State=1, Activity ID: f94c1640-731c-48e4-b423-f05a80e6043d.

[image]

Comment: Is this [post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/azure-managed-identity-authentication-for-azure-sql-db-using-azure-data-factory-d8b13afb19e7) helpful for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to login Azure SQL with an AAD administrator and create a EXTERNAL PROVIDER user. I've created a test for this.

1. Set an AAD administrator to your Azure sql.
   [image]
2. Login to your Azure sql with the AAD administrator.
   [image]
3. Create a EXTERNAL PROVIDER User with your Azure datafactory name.

```sql
CREATE USER [your Data Factory name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

ALTER ROLE [role name] ADD MEMBER [your Data Factory name];
```

[image]

4. Test connection successfully:
   [image]

Comment: In my case, I do have the Azure Data Factory resource name as a user in the Master and the Database that I wanted to create along with the DB_Owner role. Still I am facing below error:

Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'sb_server_name.database.windows.net', Database: 'database_name', User: ''. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'., SqlErrorNumber=18456,Class=14,State=1,